# index.html appears smaller than all other pages of a website

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my new website i'm designing in HTML5. 
It's a single page site with 5 different sections. 
The home page is ***index.html#home*** and all sections appear properly, except of ***index.html***, which is zoomed-out.

All sections have the same CSS:

```
width:100%;
background-color:#7fffd4;
padding:5px 0px;
margin:0px;
```

Here are the screenshots:
Normal:https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHc8W.jpg
Zoomed-out https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIedm.png

If you have any idea how to fix this i really appreciate it.

Comment: There might be a variety of unrelated factors influencing this. Could you add a link to the actual page and/or code? Also, I have to say this, make sure you are not using any addons or shortcuts that actually increase the zoom in the browser itself.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome remembers the state of the zoom for each URL you have set, make sure you haven't accidentally zoomed out on the index page.

Press **CTRL + 0** on the index page to check (or go to view > actual size).

Answer (score 3):

The Text on one section is pretty long. I think this is causing the zoom-effect. Try to shorten the text or auto-wrap it with CSS.

You could put the long text in a `<div id="someid">` and change your CSS
like this:

```
#someid {
  width: 100%;
  padding: auto 30%;
}
```

`auto` is top and bottom and `30%` is for left and right.
You should adjust the 30% like you want.
It will format your divs to always use 100% of the given browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your quick reply.
The index.html was in fact zoomed out in chrome, although i put it to 100% on some other subpage of my website.

I'm going to wrap the text anyway, that was a good idea. Thanks again.

*Cheers, stax*